# multiple value insertion from a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having form with a table with three columns namely Roll_No, Name and Marks. I am fetching the Roll_no and Name from the database. The teacher only has to enter the marks in the form against the respective student's roll no and name. I coded as shown below, but only the last value entered is getting set for all the students in the database. Its inserting the sid and roll no correctly but creating problem with marks. My database  structure for marks is sid, roll_no, marks.

Here is my code: correct me where am going wrong please.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="900" height="49" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['response']))
      { 
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\">".$_SESSION['response']."</td></tr>";    unset($_SESSION['response']);} ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="20"> Roll No.</td>
        <td align="center" width="200"> Name</td>
        <td align="center" width="20"> Marks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><input type="submit" name="next" value="submit" /></tr>
    <?php
    $sub = $_GET['sid'];

    $result = mysql_query("select * from student_record_by_faculty where sid='$sub'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows!=0)
{
        while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $r2=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select name from login where username='$r[reg_no]'"));


    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $r['reg_no']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $r2['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="centre"><input type="number" name="marks" />
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['next']))
    {
        $marks = $_POST['marks'];
        $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks(sid, reg_no, first_sessional) VALUES('$sub','$r[reg_no]','".$_POST['marks']."')");
        echo $q;
        if($q)
        {       echo "marksheet updated you are being directed to marksheet page";
             sleep(2);
                header("Location:marksheet.php");
        }
    }
    ?>    
    </td></tr> 


  <?php                         
     }
}
    else
    {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
//mysqli_close($con);*/
?>
```

Comment: is the above code file called `marksheet.php` ? Are you calling `session_start();` somewhere in your code ?

Comment: P.S: Forgot to add, when the teacher is entering the marks, the Roll_No and Name of the student is displayed, he only has to enter the marks against the student.

Comment: no, it test1.php actually what i am doing is after inserting the values am directing it back to previous page marksheet.php where the teacher will have list of other subjects. ya am calling the session.

Comment: This coding pattern is really discouraged, one of the reasons being that it's painful to debug, as you are seeing.  You should not interweave your PHP and HTML this way, and you should not depend on variables loaded in the script but not matched against the form when doing an insert ( but you **should** sanitize and validate any input from from the form ).  If you switched to using PDO for the insert and separate the form from the php, you could not only find your problem faster but also expand the form to allow the professor to do roll for all students on one form.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: I can see your issue very clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you have the insert logic wrapped inside the loop which is displaying the rows of the table. Which was being executed completely wrong. I have adjust your code and here is a version that can work. This is not also 100 using best practices i've only adjust so that you can understand the change that has been made.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="900" height="49" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['response']))
    { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\">".$_SESSION['response']."</td></tr>";    unset($_SESSION['response']);} ?>
<tr>
    <td align="center" width="20"> Roll No.</td>
    <td align="center" width="200"> Name</td>
    <td align="center" width="20"> Marks</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='3'><input type="submit" name="next" value="submit" /></td></tr>
<?php
$sub = $_GET['sid'];

$result = mysql_query("select * from student_record_by_faculty where sid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($sub) . "'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrows!=0)
{
    while(($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)) != FALSE)
    {
        $r2=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select name from login where username='$r[reg_no]'"));
        ?>
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="reg_no[]" value="<?php echo $r['reg_no']; ?>" />
    <td align="center"><?php echo $r['reg_no']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $r2['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" name="marks[]" /></td>
</tr> 
<?php                         
    }
}    ?>
</table>
    <input type="hidden" name="subid" value="<?php echo $_GET['sid']; ?>" />
</form>

<?php 
//mysqli_close($con);*/


if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
    $marks = $_POST['marks'];
    $i=0;
    foreach ($marks as $mark) {
        $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks(sid, reg_no, first_sessional) VALUES('" . $_GET['subid'] . "','" . $_POST['reg_no'][$i++] . "','" . $mark ."')");
    }
    header("Location:marksheet.php");

}


?>
```

Comment: in this statement, its displaying the value of reg_no correctly but in the next line, am unable to take the value to insert it into database. here am wanting to directly insert the reg_no which am getting from the first query, but you have used post method...

<td align="center"><?php echo $r['reg_no']; ?></td>

 $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks(sid, reg_no, first_sessional) VALUES('" . $_GET['subid'] . "','" . $_POST['reg_no'][$i++] . "','" . $mark ."')");